# VUEX State has been updated, but page content is not updated 0

Tags: vuex, nuxt.js

I use Nuxt, auth & VUEX state to control the login & logout process.

After I log in, the VUEX state is already updated. But the page still not show my name. Only after I refresh the page, the page content is updated. I don't know why that happens. Could you please provide some hint on that?

Before page refresh:
[image: Before page refresh]

After page refresh:
[image: After page refresh]

Below is my code snippet:
[image]

Comment: I found something new, it only occur when redirecting the current to another one. Ex: After logout, the page is redirect to home page. And the issue happened.   I use the below code snippet: async onLogout() {
      await this.$auth.logout();
    } //it will redirect to home page.

Answer (score 0):

You need 'computed' the value with a getter which view version are you using ?

An exemple in 'vue-property-decorator':

```
get updateResult() {
    return this.result;
}
```

Comment: For use the value you not need execute a function, it's a variable:                                                  <div>{{ this.updateResult }}</div>